# <body> and <html> height and layout trouble

Tags: html, css, height, wrapper

I've got two pages, page A which has a lot of content and requires scrolling down, and page B which has little content and only takes up half the browser window. I'm trying to stick a footer down at the very bottom of both pages, regardless of the size of their content.

Here is what I've been trying to do. I've two containers inside the body, one for footer and one for everything else, call it main-wrapper. I've put borders aroudn the wrappers and body to see wheree they take up. Main wrapper will take up all the content on page A, but on page B it will only sit around the actual content, it's bottom-border is half way down the page, even though the body body takes up the full screen. I've set the main-warpper height to 100% so why won't it take uo the full body???

Comment: google sticky css footer

Comment: I've tried. I'm following a general solution that they all take and none of them work.

Comment: Ok, well the next step for you would be to make a bare-bones example using a jsfiddle, and link that solution so we can help you further.

Comment: Here's my html. I'm using exactly what this commonly referenced site site suggests, yet the footer still sits in the middle of the page.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would approach this situation. It sounds like you need to set a min-height on your main-wrapper instead of just having it's height set to 100% of the filling container.  Due to screen sizes greatly varying from user to user, you'll need to use a little javascript/jquery to try and calculate the page height.  Try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var pageHeight = $("body").height();
   pageHeight -= 200; // Whatever the height of your footer is. Make sure to subtract that out
   $("#main-wrapper").css("min-height", pageHeight + "px");
});
```